# How to multply two float arrays using sse?

Tags: c++, sse

```
void sse_mul_float(float* a, float* b, int N)                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  int nb_iters = N / 4;                                                                                                                                                                                         

  __m128* l = (__m128*)a;                                                                                                                                                                                      
  __m128* r = (__m128*)b;                                                                                                                                                                                      

  for (int i = 0; i < nb_iters; ++i, ++l, ++r)                                                                                                                                                                   
    _mm_store_ps(l, _mm_mul_ps (l, r));
}
```

I would like to multiply elements of one float array with another one and I would like to store the results in the first array

I am getting this error: 
cannot convert ‘__m128* {aka __vector(4) float*}’ to ‘__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__m128 _mm_mul_ps(__m128, __m128)’

Comment: I can convert a `float*` to a `float` by adding a `*` before the name. Use `*l` and `*r`.

Comment: also: `N / 4` is not really nice, use `N / sizeof(float)`

Comment: You mean like this:     _mm_store_ps(l, _mm_mul_ps(*l, *r));  ?

Comment: @StackDanny if `sizeof(float)` isn't 4 then this code cannot compile anyway because the x86 intrinsics aren't going to exist

Comment: @StackDanny @harold If at all, it should be `N / (sizeof(__m128)/sizeof(float))`, i.e., divide by the number of floats inside a packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void sse_mul_float(float* a, float* b, int N)                                                                                                                                                                          
{          
  int nb_iters = N / sizeof(float);                                                                                                                                                                                         

  float c;
  __m128* l = (__m128*)a;                                                                                                                                                                                      
  __m128* r = (__m128*)b;


  for (int i = 0; i < nb_iters; ++i, ++l, ++r)
  {
      _mm_store_ps(&a[i*4], _mm_mul_ps(*l, *r));
  }

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(float)` is very misleading here. You need to divide by the number of floats inside a `__m128` which just accidentally is 4 as well.